# Google Sheets Advanced Query

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to extract value for a given Month, Day, and Time of the year. I am trying to find the distribution of Demand for a possible outcome of Demand for the next year (24 hours * 365 days = 8760 data points)

For example, if I want to find the distribution of past demand on January 1st then I want to extract the demand value for the January 1st in every year at a specific time of the day within the data frame.

I provided a picture below on what I am trying to achieve.

Let's call the past demand "Past Demand SS" and the Expected Demand "E_Demand SS".
"Past Demand SS" has 3 columns and 35041 rows.
"E_Demand SS" has 3 columns and 8760 rows.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this instead of entering it in manually?

[image: What I want to accomplish]

[image: Query]

[image: The Worksheet I want to Query]

Comment: Have you tried using QUERY of FILTER formulas?

Comment: Yes I have tried this query:

=QUERY('kW usage by hour'!A2:F35041,"SELECT A, B, C WHERE D = '1/1' AND B = '12:00:00 AM'")

I added pictures above to show what is being referenced in the query

Comment: I had got it. I had to convert the formatting of the dates and time to string values and then copy and paste them as value only. Thanks

Comment: You can post your answer